# Upload files with Jquery File Upload in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

Does anyone has a clean suggestion of instantiate this jquery's useful library.

I need to submit files and manage the **Json** response from the server. 
I always get none json response within the **Js** code. I have reviewed some articles mentioning it but the code doesn't fit to the purpose.
The situation is: I achieve the submition and saving in the database but the Json response never arrives.

Thanks in advance.

This is my view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#formUplImg").fileupload({
    dataType: "json",
    url:'@Url.Action("CreateJson","ProductImage")',
    done: function (e, data) {
        alert(data.StatusMessage);
    }
});

</script>



@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateJson", "ProductImage", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formUplImg", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "jqtransform" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="rowElem">
    <input type="file" id="Content" name="Content" />
</div>
<div class="rowElem">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => item.Content)
</div>

<div class="rowElem">@Html.JQueryUI().Button("Guardar imagen", ButtonElement.Button, ButtonType.Submit, new { id = "guardar_imagen" })</div>
}
```

This is my controller action code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult CreateJson(UploadedFileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileInfo.Content == null)
                throw new Exception("Hubo problemas con el envío. Seleccione un archivo a subir");

            var file = new TempDocument
            {
                CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                CreationTime = DateTime.Now,
                FileName = fileInfo.Content.FileName,
                MimeType = fileInfo.Content.ContentType,
                Size = fileInfo.Content.ContentLength,
                Content = new byte[fileInfo.Content.ContentLength]//Image content to save
            };

            fileInfo.Content.InputStream.Read(file.Content, 0, fileInfo.Content.ContentLength);//Reading image content into ProductImage object
            DocumentsManager.StorePendingDocuments.Add(file);
            DocumentsManager.SaveTempDocuments();//Store each document uploaded to: TempDocument Table

            TempData["SuccessMsg"] = "The image was saved successfully";

            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { Success = true, StatusMessage = "El objeto fue insertado correctamente" });
            return Content(json, "application/json");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            TempData["ErrorMsg"] = exception.Message;
            var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { Success = false, StatusMessage = exception.Message });
            return Content(json, "application/json");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use return type of Action as ActionResult and use:

```
`return Json(new { Result = "Success" });`
```

So that on success you will get Json object containing result value.